# Не могу понять что не так:(

Tags: c#

Не могу понять в чем проблема.;(
У меня есть несколько классов: Игрок, Карта и Колода. Класс "Карта" принимает в себя конструктор, автореализуемые свойство и метод по выведению информации о карте. Класс "Колода" соединяет в себе все методы по эксплуатации колоды. Это создание самой колоды, метод тасования колоды, метод выдачи карт из колоды игроку и метод, который показывает саму колоду карт. Класс "Игрок" имеет в себе два поля: лист с картами игрока, экземпляр класса "Колода" и два метода: один добавляет карты в колоду игрока, а второй показывает карты игрока.
Так вот в чем суть, у меня добавляются карты в колоду игрока, все выводится и показывается, но из листа с колодой карт не удаляются карты, которые я добавляю в колоду игрока. Проверял в дебаге, все методы отрабатывают корректно. Что не так? Добрые люди, подскажите!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CSLight
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string CommandTakeCard = "1";
            const string CommandShowPlayerCards = "2";
            const string CommandShowCardsDeck = "3";
            const string CommandExit = "Exit";

            Player player = new Player();
            CardsDeck cardsDeck = new CardsDeck();

            cardsDeck.AddCards();

            bool isProgramWork = true;

            while (isProgramWork)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Выберите одну из операций");
                Console.WriteLine($"{CommandTakeCard}-взять карту или карты" +
                    $"\n{CommandShowPlayerCards}-показать карты игрока" +
                    $"\n{CommandShowCardsDeck}-показать колоду карт" +
                    $"\n{CommandExit}-выйти из программы");
                string userChoice = Console.ReadLine();

                switch (userChoice)
                {
                    case CommandTakeCard:
                        player.TakeCard();
                        break;

                    case CommandShowPlayerCards:
                        player.ShowPlayerCards();
                        break;

                    case CommandShowCardsDeck:
                        cardsDeck.ShowCards();
                        break;

                    case CommandExit:
                        isProgramWork = false;
                        break;
                }

                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.Clear();
            }
        }

        class Player
        {
            private CardsDeck _cardsDeck = new CardsDeck();
            private List<Card> _playersCards = new List<Card>();

            public void TakeCard()
            {
                _cardsDeck.GetCard(_playersCards);
            }

            public void ShowPlayerCards()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < _playersCards.Count; i++)
                {
                    _playersCards[i].ShowInfo();
                }
            }
        }

        class Card
        {
            public Card(string suit, string name, string color)
            {
                Suit = suit;
                Name = name;
                Color = color;
            }

            public string Suit { get; private set; }
            public string Name { get; private set; }
            public string Color { get; private set; }

            public void ShowInfo()
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Карта - {Suit}, Масть - {Name}, Цвет - {Color}");
            }
        }

        class CardsDeck
        {
            private List<Card> _cards = new List<Card>();

            public void AddCards()
            {
                string peaks = "\u2660";
                string diamonds = "\u2666";
                string worms = "\u2665";
                string cross = "\u2663";

                _cards.Add(new Card("Король", peaks, "Черный"));
                _cards.Add(new Card("Валет", diamonds, "Красный"));
                _cards.Add(new Card("Дама", cross, "Черный"));
                _cards.Add(new Card("Туз", worms, "Красный"));
                _cards.Add(new Card("Король", cross, "Красный"));
                _cards.Add(new Card("Десять", diamonds, "Черный"));
                _cards.Add(new Card("Девять", peaks, "Черный"));
                _cards.Add(new Card("Восемь", worms, "Красный"));
                _cards.Add(new Card("Семь", cross, "Черный"));
                _cards.Add(new Card("Шесть", peaks, "Черный"));
                _cards.Add(new Card("Король", peaks, "Черный"));
                _cards.Add(new Card("Дама", cross, "Черный"));
                _cards.Add(new Card("Валет", worms, "Красный"));
                _cards.Add(new Card("Семь", diamonds, "Красный"));
                _cards.Add(new Card("Восемь", cross, "Черный"));
                _cards.Add(new Card("Туз", peaks, "Черный"));
                _cards.Add(new Card("Туз", worms, "Красный"));
                _cards.Add(new Card("Девять", peaks, "Черный"));
                _cards.Add(new Card("Девять", diamonds, "Красный"));

                Shuffling(_cards);
            }

            public void GetCard(List<Card> playersCards)
            {
                AddCards();

                Console.WriteLine("Сколько карт нужно игроку?");
                string userChoice = Console.ReadLine();

                if (int.TryParse(userChoice, out int numberOfCards))
                {
                    if (_cards.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCards; i++)
                        {
                            _cards.Remove(_cards[i]);
                            playersCards.Add(_cards[i]);
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine("Карты добавлены в колоду");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Карты в колоде закончились");
                    }
                }
            }

            public void ShowCards()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < _cards.Count; i++)
                {
                    _cards[i].ShowInfo();
                }
            }

            private void Shuffling(List<Card> cards)
            {
                Random random = new Random();

                Card temp;

                for (int i = cards.Count - 1; i >= 1; i--)
                {
                    int j = random.Next(i + 1);

                    temp = cards[j];
                    cards[j] = cards[i];
                    cards[i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Сколько раз у вас написано `new CardsDeck();`? Я вижу 2, в самой "игре" и у **каждого** игрока. То есть, у вас помимо основной колоды, у каждого игрока еще своя, из которой он берет карту, и т.д. Так может колода должна быть одна? Подумайте об этом...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс `Programm`: `CardsDeck cardsDeck = new CardsDeck();`

Класс `Player`: `private CardsDeck _cardsDeck = new CardsDeck();`

Таким образом у вас создаётся карточная колода не только для стола, но и для каждого игрока отдельно.

Давайте изменим класс `Player` так, что бы он принимал карточный стол, с которым игрок и ассоциируется:

```cs
class Player
{
    private CardsDeck _cardsDeck;
    private List<Card> _playersCards = new List<Card>();

    public Player(CardsDeck cd) {_cardsDeck = cd;}

    public void TakeCard()
    {
        _cardsDeck.GetCard(_playersCards);
    }

    public void ShowPlayerCards()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _playersCards.Count; i++)
        {
            _playersCards[i].ShowInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь при создании игрока передадим ему текущий стол:

```cs
CardsDeck cardsDeck = new CardsDeck();
Player player = new Player(cardsDeck);
```